# Table cell spacing only on first row and footer

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I have tried cell spacing combined with border-collapse but the spacing is applied all over the table I just want to add spacing between the first row and the second one, and also the footer. I'm using MUI styled components for this with react. I already tried using 2 tables and it works but that's not how it should be coded. Also tried to apply several CSS rules like border-spacing, border-collapse.

I want to make a table looks like this:

[image]

Here is an example of the current code.

```html
<table class="tableClass">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>header 4</th>
      <th>header 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <td>content 1</td>
    <td>content 2</td>
    <td>content 3</td>
    <td>content 4</td>
    <td>content 5</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
.tableClass{ border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 0px;}
```

**UPDATE (Solution)**

Leaving the empty cell and applying `empty-cell: hide` rule creates the effect required. Thanks for the help and also my apologies for the poor written question.

Comment: Please see [ask]. What have you tried? You're expected to make an effort and show your code.

Comment: @isherwood thanks for the recommendations, updated now

Comment: There's your HTML, but no attempt at a solution.

Comment: It would help if the image and the code sample labelled the cells a bit more clearly where would header 1, header 2 appear and to not confuse header 1 with header 1 maybe use header 3 and 4

Comment: insert an empty second cell in all rows that has no borders?

Comment: @Johannes thanks for your comment, leaving the empy cell and applying `empty-cell: hide` rule helps me find right solution

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited code available you could use css psuedo selectors such as [:first-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/) or [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) to target styles to the first/2nd columns/rows. In this example I expand the padding of the first cells in a column. Now this looks ok if there are no table borders but will be a problem if you want to show the table borders.

```css
.tableClass tr > th:first-of-type, 
.tableClass tr > td:first-of-type { padding-right: 40px; }
```

```html
<table class="tableClass">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
      <th>header 3</th>
      <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What you actually want is multiple tables or even better CSS grid.
With multiple tables you would need to change your components out put the separate tables instead of just new cells and depend on css to fix the positioning. If that is a problem a hacky work around could be to wrap all content inside the cell with a div that you style with borders like this:

```css
.tableClass{ border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; }
.tableClass tr div { border: 1px solid #000; padding: 2px 4px; min-height: 1.2rem; }
.tableClass tr > th:first-of-type, 
.tableClass tr > td:first-of-type { padding-right: 40px; }
```

```html
<table class="tableClass">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><div>header 1</div></th>
      <th><div>header 2</div></th>
      <th><div>header 3</div></th>
      <th><div>header 4</div></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <td><div>cell 1</div></td>
    <td><div>cell 2</div></td>
    <td><div>cell 3</div></td>
    <td><div>cell 4</div></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is problematic though as you have to set the div to a fixed height or find a way to make it fill the box. I would definitely recommend css grid if you are using this for any kind of complex layout.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this gave me the guide I needed, I found that leaving the cell empty and using `empty-cell: hide` property that will create the effec that I need.